# how to get websocket api datas with socketio

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Couple of time I tried to get data with socketio from websocket in laravel. But I cannot to reach datas. When I tried in postman coming datas. I codes are:

```
import { io } from "https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.esm.min.js";

    const socket = io("wss://website.com", {
        reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
        transports : ['websocket'],
        query: {
            "type": "available",
            "playId": "000000000"
        }
    });
    const connect = socket.connect();

    console.log(connect);
```

For example in postman coming datas like this:

```
{"result":[{"Id":"1089292102","result":"2x","time":"Apr 19, 2023 4:01:15 PM","rc":1,"powerUp":false,"pe":false,"powerUpList":[],"powerUpTotal":2.0,"pr":1.0,"mr":2.0}]}
```

Comment: You cannot use socket.io to connect to a websocket server. You need to use some other package like `ws` for that.